How to force an ignite node to load data from the database and not from the nodes present in the cluster?
I am again introducing the problem that I am still not able to resolve. I have 3 ignite instances(A,B,C) running out of which one instance(A) is connected to the database and the other 2 instances(B,C) simply copy the data from this node. While releasing, A is deployed first and then the remaining 2 nodes are deployed. Now, if A is down for some reason(network failure let's say) and the downtime is for 1 minute. The other 2 nodes are not affected but for this duration of 1 minute if there are any data changes happening in the database...it won't be recorded in these nodes as they just copied the data from A. Now, A goes up after 1 minute but instead of loading the latest data from the database it copies the stale data present in the already running nodes in the cluster.
Also, to make it a bit more clearer we don't perform any writes on the cache. Instead we do it on postgres which fires a trigger on a channel that is caught by my application running on ignite.
I tried setting the rebalance mode to NONE for A and for the other 2 nodes I kept it default i.e. ASYNC hoping that this would help me forcing ignite to load data from the disk. It didn't work as ignite expects all the nodes to have same rebalance mode in a cluster.
    val discoverySpi = TcpDiscoverySpi()

    val ipFinder = TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder()

    ipFinder.setAddresses(clusterIPs?.split(",") ?: listOf())
    ipFinder.setShared(true)
    discoverySpi.setIpFinder(ipFinder)

    val igniteConfig = IgniteConfiguration()

    igniteConfig.discoverySpi = discoverySpi

    igniteConfig.metricsLogFrequency = 0 
    igniteConfig.setClientMode(false)
    igniteConfig.igniteInstanceName = System.getenv("ignite.instance-name")
    val atomicConfiguration = AtomicConfiguration()
    atomicConfiguration.cacheMode = CacheMode.REPLICATED
    igniteConfig.atomicConfiguration = atomicConfiguration
    igniteConfig.setCacheConfiguration("Model Name".cacheConfiguration.setRebalanceMode(CacheRebalanceMode.NONE)}


How do you load the data from Postgres to Ignite during normal operation? Use the same logic to refresh the data that was updated while the node was down?

That's the case. While starting the application, in order to load data I normally do .loadCache(null). But when a node goes down I am not able to track it which is why I am facing this issue. Do you know how to track the entry and exit of nodes?

The question says that only Node A is responsible for loading the data, right? Have you tried LifecycleBean to run the logic on node start? https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/lifecycle/LifecycleBean.html

This worked. I can now track the entry and exit of the nodes. Thank you so much @PavelTupitsyn
